# Pygame zooming/scrolling window

Tags: python, scroll, zooming, transform, pygame

Im currently working on a project with pygame and am in need of being able to view part of a surface, moving around, zooming in and out ect

Can anyone recommend a way of achieving this efficently, i have it working in a convoluted method at the moment but it is too slow and reduces the game to about 1fps when zoomed out to view the whole area. (my version of only scrolling and no zooming works fine with no lagging)

Looking though the docs pygame.transform.scroll looks promising but i am unsure how i would correctly implement it with pygame.transform.scale for zooming in and out

Any help welcome

**update:**
I fiddled around for a bit and got it working scaleing objects and their positions before bliting them. I have now hit the problem that the scaling looks unatural because of the low resolution of the pygame scroll wheel events so I am now trying to impliment some kind of smoothing.

Comment: You might find an answer over at gamedev.stackexchange.com if you don't find anything here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what, exactly, you are doing. I can however say that it doesn't sound like you are approaching the problem in a way that fits Pygame.

It sounds to me like you are relying on software scaling algorithms, which is what Pygame uses, to scale a large picture (the entire game world) to a much smaller size. Anything like that, for large surfaces, and on each frame, is going to greatly strain your CPU.

If zooming is really important, I'd recommend a change to a library that has hardware accelerated scaling, i.e [pyglet](http://pyglet.org). After all, how often did you see games zoom out in the days before GPUs? Virtually never, that's how often.

Comment: Had a brief look at pyglet and although it wouldnt be too bad to miagrate (not much rendering code yet) im not up to learing a new module. Do you think it would be suitable to try and scale the objects as they are drawn instead of the whole surface (virtualy all of the game elements are done by pygame.draw or pygame.gfxdraw)

Comment: Yes, you can absolutely do that. It requires a bit of work on your part, and you will lose some fidelity. At extreme zoom out, you might need sub-pixel precision (which you can't really get with pygame) to make it look good.

Comment: after a while i actually went back and started using pyglet (there wasn't actually that much drawing code to transfer) but i still cant figure out how to switch between game and menus ect in pyglet

Answer (score 0):

You can use pygame with OpenGL, since you are already familiar with pygame. Otherwise pyglet is a similar opengl library.

Answer (score 0):

For a game that I have never finished I used trigonometry to get the new drawing positions with a freely zoomed and turned camera (bit complicated). It didn't really take to much time to calculate but I think it is more efficient to use other libraries. But if you want some examples just ask.

Comment: First I calculated the angle and distance between an object and my camera. Then I calculated the new drawing position with these values and the turning angle of my camera and its height.